# angular 8 ng-bootstrap 5.2.2 reactive forms, NgbDatepicker not working

Tags: angular, ng-bootstrap

Why is the Bootstrap datepicker not working with reactive forms ?

```
<input formControlName="startDate" class="form-control" [ngClass]="{ 'is-invalid': submitted && f.startDate.errors }" ngbDatepicker #d />

export class AddEventComponent implements OnInit {

@ViewChild('d', { read: NgbDatepicker, static: true }) d: NgbDatepicker;
```

If I put:

```
<input formControlName="startDate" class="form-control" [ngClass]="{ 'is-invalid': submitted && f.startDate.errors }" ngbDatepicker #d="ngbDatepicker" />
```

I get the error: `There is no directive with "exportAs" set to "ngbDatepicker"`.

Comment: The error: There is no directive with "exportAs" set to "ngbDatepicker" was because I did not include the NgbModule in the module where I need the date picker. But the date picker is still not showing...

Comment: I also imported the boostrap css in styles.scss with: @import "../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css";
I verified and the styles are there however the date picker is still not showing.

Comment: check if your "form" has value. I usually write `<form *ngIf="form" [formGroup]="form">...</form>` to avoid initials errors -if you create the form in a ngOnInit, e.g.-

Comment: I added the *ngIf attribute and it is the same behavior. Yes I create the form in ngOnInit. I don't have any errors in the console.

Comment: Inline datepicker works fine: <ngb-datepicker #d></ngb-datepicker>. But popup up doesn't: <input type="text" id="startDate2" ngbDatepicker #d="ngbDatepicker" />

Comment: In https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-28tfhg?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html work ok, can you share a stackblitz?

Comment: @Eliseo, thanks for the sample. I did not know that you had to open it explicitly in order to see it. Thanks a lot. If you want you can write an answer to the question and I will accept your answer.

Comment: if you see the button click, you see `(click)="d.toggle()`, "d" is the reference variable, see that the input has  `#d="ngbDatepicker"`, you can also add in input a `(focus)="d.toggle()"`, toggle is one of the methods o the ngbInputDatePicker  https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/datepicker/api#NgbInputDatepicker

Comment: Yes, it totally makes sense.  I was also using in the code ngbDatepicker type instead of ngbInputDatePicker, and I was confused why the methods toggle, open, etc were not available on it.